# How does a overloaded sort() with a third parameter (i.e. comparator function) work?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std-pair

I have a vector of a pair:

```
vector<pair<char,int> > pAB;
```

I ordered it with the sort function. The sort function has a third parameter (may be a function that return a boolean or a boolean itself) because I decided to order it in ascending order. For that you need this sortbysec function:

```
bool sortbysec(const pair<char,int> &a,
         const pair<char,int> &b){   
         return (a.second < b.second);}
```

When I used this function  I didn't have to send a parameter:

```
 sort(pAB.begin(),pAB.end(),sortbysec);
```

I want to know why this worked.

note: I already look for it on the Internet didn't find anything.

Comment: "i didn't have to send a parameter:" - what do you call that third "thing" you sent to `std::sort` ? If you're asking why `std::sort(pAB.begin(), pAB.end())` (code not shown) would work, it's because [there is a `operator <` overload for `std::pair<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) provided by the standard library, which the default comparator, [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), invokes..

Comment: Look up function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` function automatically assign a *pair* to both `a` and `b`.

The function you use (here, `sortbysec`) needs to have a return type of `Boolean`.

By defining it in this way:

```
bool sortbysec(const pair<char,int> &a, const pair<char,int> &b){   
   return (a.second < b.second);
}
```

, pairs inside vector are sorted in descending order based on `second` value of each pair, when `(a.second < b.second)` is `true`.

[More info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/):

```
void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);

comp
    Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, 
    and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the 
    element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific 
    strict weak ordering it defines.The function shall not modify any of its arguments.
    This can either be a function pointer or a function object.
```

Comment: I think the question is about the existance of function pointers: how is it possible to pass a function itself as a parameter?